# Ubuntu server Freezing every night, what this syslog entry means?

Tags: 20.04, cron, lts, syslog

My server was running nice, but since some weeks ago it started to hang up during the night even after I removed some potencial problematic apps, I imagined it could be either power delivery, some weird idle state or cron based. Today I opened the syslog file and something interesting popped up as per the images at 02:17

> Apr 5 02:17:01 homeserver CRON[285582] (root) CMD ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)

7:23 was  when I woke up, noticed and rebooted the server. Also bellow is the crontab -e file, there is nothing on it schedduled to take place at the time the server hangs up. Anyone has some idea on what the problem might be?

sudo crontab -e:

```
# System Backup at Friday 15pm
00 15 * * 5 mountpoint /mnt/media && rsync -aAXv --delete --exclude=/dev/* --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/sys/* --exclude=/tmp/* --exclude=/run/* --exclude=/mnt/* --U1 

# Backup MEDIA Directory, NextCloud & Network drives for parity
00 09 * * * mountpoint /mnt/Backup && rsync -aAXSv --delete --exclude="lost+found" --exclude=".cache" /mnt/media/ /mnt/Backup

# Fix ownership of folders 
00 15 * * * setfacl -R -m "u:plex:rwx" /mnt/video 
00 16 * * * setfacl -R -m "u:plex:rwx" /mnt/audio 
00 17 * * * setfacl -R -m "u:sonar:rwx" /mnt/video 
00 18 * * * setfacl -R -m "u:radarr:rwx" /mnt/video 

# Backup Music Collection
00 15 * * 7 mountpoint /mnt/media && rsync -aAXv --delete /mnt/audio/MUSIC /mnt/media/Backups/MUSIC 

#Photoprism indexing
00 4 * * * /usr/bin/docker exec -it photoprism_protoprism_1 /photoprism/bin/photoprism index 

#Weekly updates 
00 23 * * 7 apt-get update 
00 00 * * 1 apt-get upgrade -y
```

[var/syslog][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hGZ8.jpg

kern.log from the time frame:

```
...
Apr  4 08:56:47 homeserver kernel: [  778.148042] eth0: renamed from veth2073901
Apr  4 08:56:47 homeserver kernel: [  778.167947] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth59d8998: link becomes ready
Apr  4 09:45:33 homeserver kernel: [ 3703.089539] fwupd[45836]: segfault at 8 ip 000055aa3b5db10d sp 00007ffe6fec4540 error 4 in fwupd[55aa3b5d6000+26000]
Apr  4 09:45:33 homeserver kernel: [ 3703.089546] Code: ff 85 c0 0f 85 97 02 00 00 48 8b 7c 24 30 e8 5a d5 ff ff e9 67 01 00 00 48 8b 44 24 28 48 8d 3d d9 14 02 00 41 be 01 00 00 00 <48> 8b 70 08 31 c0 e8 08 f4 ff ff 4d 85 e4 74 08 4c 89 e7 e8 2b db
Apr  4 17:48:11 homeserver kernel: [32661.793069] perf: interrupt took too long (2534 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 78750
Apr  5 00:13:57 homeserver kernel: [55806.993146] fwupd[260498]: segfault at 8 ip 0000557e9d14e10d sp 00007ffca9bb9f60 error 4 in fwupd[557e9d149000+26000]
Apr  5 00:13:57 homeserver kernel: [55806.993152] Code: ff 85 c0 0f 85 97 02 00 00 48 8b 7c 24 30 e8 5a d5 ff ff e9 67 01 00 00 48 8b 44 24 28 48 8d 3d d9 14 02 00 41 be 01 00 00 00 <48> 8b 70 08 31 c0 e8 08 f4 ff ff 4d 85 e4 74 08 4c 89 e7 e8 2b db
Apr  5 00:38:18 homeserver kernel: [57268.594181] perf: interrupt took too long (3179 > 3167), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 62750
Apr  5 07:23:38 homeserver kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xea, date = 2021-03-08
Apr  5 07:23:38 homeserver kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-107-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-058) (gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)) #121-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 24 16:04:27 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-107.121-generic 5.4.174)
Apr  5 07:23:38 homeserver kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-107-generic root=UUID=a71686d4-7ed5-4da9-913f-87eeb1746d72 ro
Apr  5 07:23:38 homeserver kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Apr  5 07:23:38 homeserver kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Apr  5 07:23:38 homeserver kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Apr  5 07:23:38 homeserver kernel: [    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
Apr  5 07:23:38 homeserver kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Apr  5 07:23:38 homeserver kernel: [    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
...
```

Edit: One thing I´ve noticed is that it worked fine all day when i was out connecting to it outside home, when I got home that it started a time machine backup using netatalk avahi and I was trasfering some files to the network disk it hang up, I've deleted netatalk avahi and am using another backup method by samba, removed some old docker containers that I don´t need anymore and all, also changed the hub where the drives are connected, it managed to survive until 6:59AM, I checked kern.log, a instance of lidarr was the last working service at hang up time, so I disabled it also. let´s see if today it will reach 24h without hanging up.

Comment: What did you already try to troubleshoot? Did you try disabling all your cron jobs, and see if it's still a problem? This is troubleshooting 101.

Comment: However, that `run-parts` message is completely normal, and part of the usual `cron` runtime. This is not the issue.

Comment: previous troublesshoting included deleting some recently installed apps that perhaps where causing the issue, today was the first time I got something useful from syslog related to a hang-up, previously the logs didn't trace back far enough, I don't know if I was doing something wrong or if that is the expected behavior of syslog.

Comment: Also, why don't you have kernel messages in the syslog? Try having a look at either `/var/log/kern.log` or `dmesg` at the time the server shuts down.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the log messages **as text** instead of showing a screenshot.

Comment: `run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly` isn't related to root's "personal" crontab (sudo crontab -e) - it's from the system-wide `/etc/crontab` file running the files in `/etc/cron.hourly`

Comment: added kern.log file

Comment: So there are no kernel or syslog errors related to this. I would then guess it's a heat or power issue.

Comment: If that´s the case then, I believe that perhaps it´s a power delivery failure, since this machine is pretty new and never had overheating problens.

Comment: Does `journalctl -p 3 -b -1` show anything useful? It will list any errors of any type in the period of the previous boot to shutdown (or freeze). Change the -1 to -2 for the boot before that (etc) if you have rebooted more than once

Comment: journalctl -p 3 -b -2 last entry (today it hang up at 6:59AM) shows > Apr 06 06:26:13 homeserver systemd-network-wait-online[108946]: Event loop failed: Connection timed out

Comment: I’m not sure that error is causing your problem but a quick search with your error message produces this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381448/systemd-networkd-wait-online-failure#452606 It may be helpful to edit the wait-online service as suggested